# SSRS Subreport not behaving correctly

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I have a SSRS main report in which I am using a subreport. Based on some parameter value I want to show the reports.

For example, I have a parameter called "view" in which I have 2 options:

1. Detailed view
2. Overview

When a user selects the "Detalied view" option it should show the subreport
Also, when a user selects "Overview" that data comes from the Main Report.

For both the Reports I am using 2 different datasets. The problem is when I run the subreport separately, it works fine. But when I call it from the main Report for some selection criteria, it shows the subreport. But for some other it gives me error that one or more parameter is not supplied to the subreport.

I don't understand the issue. Please any one has any idea please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look at the Parameters page of the subreport properties, can you show us what it says there?

Comment: I bet when you run the sub-report directly you are passing over a required parameter value, however, you are omitting that value in the parameter handshake from main report to sub report.

Comment: i am having same parameters in both the Reports. and also in my sql stored procedue. still i dont get it where m i lacking .

Comment: Hi @DanScally i have mapped the Parameters of subreport as well

Comment: Hi @DanScally i am not able to post here an image is it not allowed here . or how can i post my report image here

Comment: swat - http://imgur.com/ - for example here's what I would expect to see in the Parameters tab: http://i.imgur.com/2L51bpp.png

Comment: @DanScally due to seurity reason i am not able to post the image here ..but i undersatnd what u want to say but i already verified it .all the parameters are mapped correctly . Only i have 3 paramters in my Subreport Debug = 0 ,WithTrans= 0 and PackageName=USP_FillTale which i can not pass through the main report. so i  assigned the above values to the parameters in my sub report

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem:
So the problem was hidden in the assignment of the parameters to the subreport.
Though i was assigning them corectly but as i had multivalued paramters SSRS itself assigning the value to the paramter with (0) in addidtion.
Ex. =Parametrs!ParameterName.Value(0)

i Removed this (0) from end , now my paramter value looks like:
ParamterName = [@ParameterName] (Not as some Expression)

and this worked as a charm. :)
i answered my question ,so that in case anyone else struggling with the same issue can get a hint.